# Remove extra cellspace from div with display: inline table?

Tags: css, padding, css-tables

This is so annoying.
In Firefox and Opera, I'm getting padding between my nested divs, but not in Chrome and Safari.

I tried `border-collapse:collapse`

But no luck, any ideas?
This extra space is screwing up my fluid footer (all div widths add up to 100%, but because Opera and Firefox add this space I never asked for (!) it overflows.

Here's my code:

Html:

```
<div id="footer">

<div class="info" id="message">&nbsp;&nbsp;Coming Soon</div>
<div class="info" id="address">The Studio 22 Belsham Street London E9 6NG</div>
<div class="info" id="telephone">+44 (0) 778 079 6488</div>
<div class="info" id="enquiries">Enquiries</div>
<div class="info" id="mailingList">Mailing List ___________________ Submit&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
z-index:3;
position:fixed; 
bottom:0; 
width:100%; 
padding: 0;
padding-bottom: 10px;
display: table;
margin: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;


}

.info{
margin:0;
padding: 0;
display: inline-table;
border: red 1px dashed;
}

#message {
    width:10%;
}

#address {
width:33%;
text-align:center;
}

#telephone {
width:20%;
text-align:center;
}

#enquiries {
width:5%;
text-align:center;
}

#mailingList {
width:29%;
text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:
Changed inline-table property to table-cell.

Makes sense...

Hope this helps someone out there.